# Is there any possibilities to embed word document inside the # windows Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any possibilities to embed word document inside Form of the # windows Application?

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the WebBrowser control for that:

```
WB.Navigate(pathToDocFile);
```

This does require Word on the PC your application runs on.

Comment: If we use like WB.Navigate(pathToDocFile) it open as a word document rather open inside the form window..but i need to open inside the form  .Have any other idea pls share with me